# Connect bootstrap panels via connector

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I have bunch of Bootstrap panels and some of them are related to each other.
Something like

```
Panel A -> Panel B -> Panel C
```

When the user will click on Panel B then Panel C will be shown and when Panel C is clicked Panel D will be shown. The problem I am facing is I need to link the parent panel to the child panel with some connector( horizontal line/arrow or some image) and I am not getting how to do it.

I want an arrow or connector from the First Title in the first column to connect to the second column and from second to third and so on

Structure of my panels is given in the fiddle link.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

[https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/af51yf0s/[![enter](https://jsfiddle.net/vatsalpande/af51yf0s/%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1V8n.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1V8n.jpg)

```
   <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class = "row">
        
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2"><h5>First Title</h5> </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2  "><h5>Second</h5></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2  "><h5>Third</h5></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2  "><h5>Fourth</h5></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2  "><h5>Fifth</h5></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2  "></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class = "row">
        
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                
                <div class="panel-group">
                   
                    <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                        <div class="panel-heading">First Title</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p> A : 5.8</p>
                            <p> B : 209M</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                        <div class="panel-heading">B</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p> A : 5.8</p>
                            <p> B : 209M</p>
                            <p> C : 209M</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2  ">
                     <div class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" >
                            <div class="panel-heading">C</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> A : 5.8</p>
                                <p> B : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                    
                        <div class="panel panel-default" >
                            <div class="panel-heading">P</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> A : 5.8</p>
                                <p> B : 209M</p>
                                <p> B : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" >
                            <div class="panel-heading">F</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> A : 5.8</p>
                                <p> B : 209M</p>
                                <p> C : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2  ">    
                    <div class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id = "siteTraffic">
                            <div class="panel-heading">P </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> A : 5.8</p>
                                <p> B : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                    
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">a</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> A : 5.8</p>
                                <p> B : 209M</p>
                                <p> C : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">W</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> Q : 5.8</p>
                                <p> V : 209M</p>
                                <p> E : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = "totalMarketingTraffic">
                            <div class="panel-heading">W</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> Q : 5.8</p>
                                <p> V : 209M</p>
                                <p> Q : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">e</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> Q : 5.8</p>
                                <p> Q : 209M</p>
                                <p> Q : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2  ">        
                    <div class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Q</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> Q : 5.8</p>
                                <p> Q : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                    
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">w</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> w : 5.8</p>
                                <p> w : 209M</p>
                                <p> w : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">w</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> w : 5.8</p>
                                <p> w : 209M</p>
                                <p> w : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">P2</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> w : 5.8</p>
                                <p> w : 209M</p>
                                <p> w : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">2</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> 2 : 5.8</p>
                                <p> w : 209M</p>
                                <p> 2 : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">w</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> 2 : 5.8</p>
                                <p> w : 209M</p>
                                <p> e : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            
            
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 emails">      
                   <div class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">eh</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> e : 5.8</p>
                                <p> e : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                    
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">w</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> q : 5.8</p>
                                <p> q : 209M</p>
                                <p> q : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">wq</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> q : 5.8</p>
                                <p> q : 209M</p>
                                <p> q : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">2l</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> w : 5.8</p>
                                <p> e : 209M</p>
                                <p> e : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         
                         <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">2rs</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> t : 5.8</p>
                                <p> t : 209M</p>
                                <p> t : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                            <div class="panel-heading">2</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> t : 5.8</p>
                                <p> t : 209M</p>
                                <p> t : 209M</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            
            
             <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 details">          
                
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">2cs</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 emails">
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <div class="panel panel-default" id = "siteTraffic">
                                <div class="panel-heading">cc/div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p> 2 : 5.8</p>
                                    <p> 2 : 209M</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    
                    
                    
                            <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                                <div class="panel-heading">ccc</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p> w : 5.8</p>
                                    <p> w : 209M</p>
                                    <p> w : 209M</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 emails">
                       
                        <div class="panel-group">
                            <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                                <div class="panel-heading">tt</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p> q : 5.8</p>
                                    <p> w : 209M</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    
                    
                    
                            <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                                <div class="panel-heading">t</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p> e : 5.8</p>
                                    <p> e : 209M</p>
                                    <p> e : 209M</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                                <div class="panel-heading">ff</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p> e : 5.8</p>
                                    <p> e : 209M</p>
                                    <p> e : 209M</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                                <div class="panel-heading">ggg</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p> YoY : 5.8</p>
                                    <p> Count : 209M</p>
                                    <p> Share : 209M</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="panel panel-default" id = " ">
                                <div class="panel-heading">wq</div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p> e : 5.8</p>
                                    <p> q : 209M</p>
                                    <p> q : 209M</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                       
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                 </div>
            </div>
        
        
        </div>
    
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the arrow glyphicon above panel group and apply CSS styles for proper positioning.

A part of your HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 emails">    
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right right-arrow"></span>
   <div class="panel-group">
```

In your CSS:

```
.right-arrow {
   position:absolute;
   margin-left: 115px;
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Working JS Fiddle: [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/532wyeee/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I want this arrow to be dynamic ?
I will need to adjust the margin -top accordingly?
How can I take care of it. For ex - I want it to be present only with the element that is clicked. If B is clicked B should have an arrow or If B & F are clicked then B& F should have the arrow?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can adjust the positioning of the arrows using the CSS styles. If you need to dynamically show the arrows on click, you can use .show() / .hide() function of Jquery. Initially hiding the arrows and on click showing the arrows.

Comment: Check the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/naga2raja/rmbub9ux/6/ . Just click on the First title and arrow comes. Implement this same functionality, wherever you need.